# Copy an Asana task/project

Tags: c#, json, asana

Is it possible to create a copy of an existing Asana task/project?

We have setup some templates that we use when a new order is coming in. The idea is to have one place to do all "paper work" when something comes in and that includes Asana.

The easiest would be to just make a copy of one of the template tasks/projects (depending on the order) and then just place the copy in the correct Team.

I could not find any endpoints for making duplicates/copies.

Each project/task has a lot of subtasks which would make it very slow if i were to create it myself since i would then have to traverse each task for subtasks, then add each task, get the id back, before adding the subtask to it.

Question is then, is there a copy endpoint? Can it be done efficiently in an other way? or do i have to go through it manually and add each one separately? Can i add a tasks with subtasks attached in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not currently support duplicating tasks or projects via the API, so for right now the only way to do it is as you described, by manually walking the tree and adding each element (we don't have a batch create endpoint either). However, you're not the first person to ask for this functionality so I'm bumping up the priority of that feature. I can't make any commitments to when we'd be able to ship this, I'm afraid, so for now you're better off working around it.

Comment: I'd like to see this feature as well, fwiw